# Google Analytics setup (advanced Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have three buttons on my website, all of the buttons opens a pop up contact form.

The three buttons are for different things e.g:

Request a call
Get a brochure
Visit us

But they all open the same form; What I want to do is use Google analytics to track the form and know what button they originally clicked; is this possible?

Can an onClick function be used on the button or something?

Really need some help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event tracking would be a better option since it won't over-inflate your pageviews. You can also set [events as goals now](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/04/new-google-analytics-events-goals.html).

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact Form', 'Button Click', 'Request a call']);">Request a call</a>
```

See the [Event Tracking Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)

Comment: Yeah thanks, I'm aware of this, and I can track the button click but when a user clicks the button; it takes them to the contact form, they then fill out a form and see the thank you page. So the contact form and thank you page are the same; what I want to know is what button they clicked to get the the thank you page: Sorry I should have been clearer.

Comment: @RuFFCuT Right. And you can put the name of the button in the event tracking code. Instead of `Request a Call` you can put in `button request call` or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

yes it's posible... '_trackPageview' it's your what are you looking for

check this links:

Official:

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2558867

Others:

http://viget.com/advance/how-to-track-internal-links-in-google-analytics (recommended)

http://www.pointit.com/how-to-track-button-clicks-with-google-analytics/